# Old SF novel, set on a military ship, one character can't order spaghetti and meatballs because of sudden mid-voyage rationing?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

This one is a real longshot. I won't be surprised if nobody can identify it. I read this book sometime in the early-to-mid-1980s. Science fiction novel, checked out from a public library, written in English, and I am pretty sure it was in hardback. Told in the third person, with multiple viewpoint characters, and a fairly serious tone -- not any sort of parody or satire, for instance. The problem is that I only remember *one short scene* clearly. Here's how it went:

1. This part of the story -- perhaps most of the story -- is taking place aboard a large spaceship with interstellar range (military, I'm nearly sure) which is large enough to require a great many crew members (probably hundreds). I think there is some sort of interstellar war going on, or else one seems likely to break out at any minute, but I can't remember details of the larger plot. I'm *sure* the crew of *this* ship were all human -- but I don't remember if their enemies (or prospective enemies) were equally human, or if this was set in one of those futures where there are other sentient alien races with their own battle fleets.
2. In the one scene that I still remember pretty well, which I believe comes near the middle of the book (definitely not in the first chapter!), the viewpoint character -- who was not a major figure in the early chapters -- has just completed a long shift. I believe he's part of the Engineering Department. Now he wants to relax by eating a nice hot dinner.
3. He decides to splurge. Instead of taking whatever is standard-issue food aboard that ship, he is willing to spend extra to get one of his favorite dishes. I don't think it was regular money he would be spending, though. The implication was that, in order to keep the ship's galley from running out of all the best items too fast during a long cruise, the rules were set up so that you had to accumulate "ration points," or something similar, for the *occasional* special treat. The rest of the time, you just ate something much simpler and cheaper, three times a day, as a way to keep your body adequately nourished. For the sake of argument, let's say that what this guy wanted was a big plateful of spaghetti and meatballs, with a certain type of salad on the side. (I don't swear that this is accurate, but I *think* he was looking forward to spaghetti and meatballs.)
4. He punches his order into a computer terminal, knowing full well that his account has more than enough "ration points" (or whatever they are called in the ship's economy) to cover the special dinner he's been promising himself.
5. Nonetheless, despite how hard he has worked to accumulate those points which are supposed to be redeemable whenever you like, he gets an error message telling him his order *cannot* be filled today because of some change in ship's policies. He throws a fit! (I don't mean literally going berserk, but he does complain loudly.)
6. I just *vaguely* remember that there was some sort of problem with the ship which had caused the Captain, earlier that day, to approve some new rationing restrictions on various things as a reaction to "a state of emergency" (or words to that effect). I don't remember if this was because of lack of energy to make nonessential things happen, or because they were carrying too many people and couldn't create special meals on demand for everyone, or what. Apparently the character I was just mentioning had not gotten the word yet when he sat down to eat dinner. I think the scene I described was followed by another scene showing the Captain (and/or some of the other senior officers) talking about how a flood of complaints was already coming in from sailors who didn't know all the facts about the problems the ship was currently facing (or was expected to face in the near future?).
7. I don't remember a thing about the cover art or the author, but I can say that if this novel had been written by any of the Really Big Names of 20th Century SF who sometimes wrote stuff with a military-style setting -- such as Poul Anderson or Gordon R. Dickson -- then I would have expected to run across the book again, sometime in the last couple of decades, and I haven't. (And it *certainly* wasn't written by Heinlein; I'm familiar with everything he published.) I'm also sure it *wasn't* a "licensed novel" set in a preexisting SF universe, such as *Star Wars* or *Star Trek*.

Comment: Rings a bell, vaguely. Could it be something by Harrison, either in his *Bill, the Galactic Hero* series or his *Stainless Steel Rat* series?

Comment: @SQB I was just going to suggest Bill the Galactic Hero, too. Pretty sure it is, but have to wait until I get home to confirm.

Comment: @Longspeak found the first one online, searched through it, no joy.

Comment: Regarding the Harry Harrison suggestion: I'm sure the book in question was **not** written as comedy/parody; it was more serious. That eliminates the first *Bill, the Galactic Hero* book (although I did check it out from the same library in the 1980s, and enjoyed it). Also, the book I want was written in third person, with multiple viewpoints -- that would help eliminate the Stainless Steel Rat books. (Besides, I'm positive I *didn't read* anything about Slippery Jim diGriz until years later! The library near where I lived in the mid-1980s didn't have any of his stuff.)

Comment: I doubt it's *The Forever War* by Aldeman, but that book does have some scenes with food rationing and kilocalorie equivalences being used to purchase goods and food.

Comment: I did read *The Forever War* back around the mid-1980s, but I've read it again since, and it wasn't this. One reason I'm sure is that "The Forever War" was very much a first-person narrative focused on one character's experiences. The book I'm vaguely remembering was third-person, with multiple viewpoint characters.

Comment: It's funny, I was also thinking Stainless Steel Rat or Bill the Galactic Hero. But the scene I think you folks are thinking of was when the titular character gets on board a ship and is forced to eat (I think it was called) rat-puppies the entire voyage. A rat-puppy was a ration sausage that got poked with a knife and blew up large and self cooked. It was tasty enough the first time, but it was the only food available the entire way. While it does have a similar feel to the OPs question, I don't think it matches.

Comment: I very, very vaguely remember something like this, and I think it was part of the Foundation cycle by Isaac Asimov. However, not 100% sure, and there are a lot of books in that series, so only a comment, but you might want to look into it. Most of the books are great reads!

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Way back around 1983 or 1984 (roughly), I read the original Foundation Trilogy, and then the recently-released *Foundation's Edge.* I've reread those stories at various times, but not for some years now. Off the top of my head, I'm not remembering a scene such I described in my original post, though -- not in one of the first 4 Foundation books. It wouldn't be in any later "Foundation" book; I'm sure they weren't even in print when I first read the scene I've described about getting an error message when trying to order a special meal aboard a starship.

Comment: Hm, okay, then you might try the Humanx Commonwealth series, by Alan Dean Foster. I mostly only read the Flinx and Pip story arch, but I did pick up another book or two from the rest of the series, so it might have been one of those.

Comment: Are you certain about the dates you read this? It reminds me of one of the Seafort saga books by David Feintuch but they were in the nineties. In one of them a batch of their ship's stores have been contaminated by Fish like aliens and the ship has to go onto emergency ration reductions

Comment: @Danny3414 -- I'm sure those are two different things. I first read a Seafort book (#3) in paperback in the mid-1990s. Since then, I've read most of the others. The story I'm asking about is something I'd read *at least* a decade earlier, in a hardback I had checked out from a public library. Of course, stories of people in spaceships having to carefully ration their food in emergency conditions have probably been done dozens of other times in the history of SF.

Comment: Worth a try I suppose 

Comment: I'm sure I have read this in the last year or two, in which case I think it might be "Tactics of Mistake" by the aforementioned Gordon R. Dickson. It's the only book that fits the bill and is on my goodreads list.

Comment: @Iolrus I have read *Tactics of Mistake* several times (although not in the last few years). I don't remember ever noticing a scene such as I described above, with a member of a starship's crew getting frustrated over his inability to redeem his "food ration points." I think the story I asked about, two years ago, was *mostly* set aboard a starship during a long voyage. Cletus Graeme was the main POV character in *Tactics,* and spent most of his time down on the ground as a soldier outsmarting his enemies during campaigns on various planets. Hope you can find what I'm looking for, though!

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it makes me think of Tau Zero by Poul Anderson, but you say it's definitely not by him.

Comment: I wonder if this couls be part of the Fixup *The Great Explosion*  by Eric Frank Russel, the last part of which is better known as "...and then there were none"?

Comment: This makes me think of a story I read in which garlic has been restricted onboard a spaceship, not due to a shortage, but because the aliens who have infiltrated the ship are allergic to it.  Our hero, in tracking down why he can't get spaghetti, uncovers the plot.