# Space adventure story: infiltration identified by restrictions on ship's menu

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, spaceship, food

This is a 1950s-era short story, I think.

If I recall correctly, the hero wants spaghetti for dinner at the mess, and while investigating why he can't get it, he uncovers a conspiracy: The aliens who are infiltrating the ship are poisoned by garlic (I think- though I don't think the aliens are vampires).

It spite of the humorous premise, I think it was played fairly straight.

Comment: There is another unanswered question on this site which sounds like it might be the same story you remember. Does it jog your memory perhaps? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145076/old-sf-novel-set-on-a-military-ship-one-character-cant-order-spaghetti-and-me

Comment: Similar, but not the same - mine is definitely a short, and focused on one character- but maybe the novel was expanded from the short story I'm looking for